# Elastic search/kibana get data from 2 documents of same Index?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, kibana, elastic-stack, kibana-7

I have 1 index in elastic search **data-production** for storing documents. This index has a common field in each document named: **document_type** to filter the different type of data.

#### I have 2 types of documents in the index: data-production

a. document_type = "**user**"

b. document_type = "**user_detail**"

### Example Data

1. Users

```
        {
          "user_id" : "123",
          "is_trial_active" : "true",
          "updated_at" : "1577338950969",
          "event_created_at" : "1577338950969",
          "document_type" : "user"
        }
```

2. Detail of User

```
    {         
       "user_id" : "123",
       "name" : "Shivam",
       "gender" : "male",
       "event_created_at" : 1575519449473,
       "phone_number" : "+91-8383838383",
       "document_type" : "user_detail",
       "created_at" : 1576049770184
    }
```

**Note**

1. user_id is the common key in both **document_type**
2. Using elasticsearch 7.3.1 version

### Question

How to fetch detail of users from **document_type**="user_details" whose **is_trial_active** is not true in **document_type**="user"?

Comment: Hi @Shivam, I'm pretty sure you can't achieve this with a single query (sorry !).

Comment: Hey @baitmbarek, there should be some way to achieve this? some nested query? I want to do this for kibana visualizations.

Comment: In fact the documents are technically unrelated and may be distributed in distinct shards. Kibana won't be able to do that for you.

Comment: You can make a relation between them if you use `join` datatype, but it will affect performance.  I can show you a fully working example if you would like.

Comment: @AssaelAzran Can you please show me working example if I don't care about performance

Comment: Using `join` datatype you will have to index parent and child documents and child documents will have to be indexed with reference to a parent id (meaning document id). can it work for you?

Comment: Maybe I missed something : @Shivam are you able/allowed to change your mapping ?

Comment: @baitmbarek hey yes I am on the early stage of the project. So yes I can change I need some proper mechanism to do that.

Comment: Great ! I tought you couldn't. You can take a look at Javin or Assael's answers. You have to define a parent / child relation in your mapping to make it work. But why don't you merge your documents (user with details) ?

Answer (score 1):

A working example:

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "document_type": {
        "type": "join",
        "relations": {
          "user": "user_detail"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Post few documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "user_id": "123",
  "is_trial_active": "false", ---> note i changed this to false for the example
  "updated_at": "1577338950969",
  "event_created_at": "1577338950969",
  "document_type": "user"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2?routing=1
{
  "user_id": "123",
  "name": "Shivam",
  "gender": "male",
  "event_created_at": 1575519449473,
  "phone_number": "+91-8383838383",
  "created_at": 1576049770184,
  "document_type": {
    "name": "user_detail",
    "parent": "1"  --> you can insert array of parents
  }
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "is_trial_active": {
                  "value": "true"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.0,
    "_routing" : "1",
    "_source" : {
      "user_id" : "123",
      "name" : "Shivam",
      "gender" : "male",
      "event_created_at" : 1575519449473,
      "phone_number" : "+91-8383838383",
      "created_at" : 1576049770184,
      "document_type" : {
        "name" : "user_detail",
        "parent" : "1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use `has_parent` query to retrieve child document

Hope the following query work for you

```
GET data-production/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": {
      "parent_type": "user",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "term": {
                "is_trial_active": {
                  "value": "true"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```